# One Script on many Game Objects OR Accessing many Game Object through one script on single GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to access some game Objects' Components i have 2 approaches:

1. A script on a GameObject(GO) accessing many GOs using `FindGameObjectsWithTag("SomeTag");`  but this not working for some GOs
2. Same Script instances (not sure it is called instance) on all that GOs i want to access their components.

My questions is that which approach is good, optimized and more sustainable for work.
And also give me alternative besides above 2 approaches if possible.

Answer (score 0):

From your given approaches:

- A script on a GameObject(GO) accessing many GOs using FindGameObjectsWithTag("SomeTag"); but this not working for some GOs

> Probably the game objects you think not working would be
>   inactive, since AFAIK, `FindGameObjectsWithTag` finds active game objects
>   only.

- Same Script instances (not sure it is called instance) on all that GOs i want to access their components.

You should make decision based on number of gameobjects that are under consideration:

*If they are limited:*

You can create an script like `GameObjectControllerScript` (attached to camera or some root gameobject, so their is only one instance of this script, [you are establishing one to may relation]), containing the references of all the game objects whose specific component you want to access and access the components on any event of your interest an dperform some operation on it.

e.g.,

```
Camera
-- Root  //<---- Attached controller script here that contains reference of StaticallyCreatedGameObject1..4
----StaticallyCreatedGameObject1
----StaticallyCreatedGameObject2
----StaticallyCreatedGameObject3
----StaticallyCreatedGameObject4
```

*If they are un-limited or generates dynamically:*

This way you can not keep reference before, so you can attach a script say `ChangeAngleScript` (to game objects that are under consideration) which accesses component of a game object and perform some operation using function `updateAngle`, and broadcast a message of `updateAngle` from some root game object.

```
Camera
-- Root   // <--- Broadcast message from here
----DynamicallyCreatedGameObject1 // <-- Attach `ChangeAngleScript` here
----DynamicallyCreatedGameObject2 // <-- Attach `ChangeAngleScript` here
----DynamicallyCreatedGameObject3 // <-- Attach `ChangeAngleScript` here
----DynamicallyCreatedGameObject4 // <-- Attach `ChangeAngleScript` here
```

Comment: With 10 GOs you can both go with either one or two, but using option two will make a room for you that if in future the game objects increases to 20 it would be easier to handle using broadcast message.